# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest difference with NodeJS fetch API

Tags: node.js, powershell, google-chrome, request, fetch

I've been trying to extract some data from a website, but the only way I'm able to get something useful is through Powershell.

The script I'm running from Powershell is:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.pelispedia.tv/api/iframes.php?id=18471?nocache" -Headers @{"method"="GET"; "authority"="www.pelispedia.tv"; "scheme"="https"; "path"="/api/iframes.php?id=18471?nocache"; "upgrade-insecure-requests"="1"; "user-agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"; "accept"="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"; "referer"="https://www.pelispedia.tv/pelicula/el-nino-que-domo-el-viento/"; "accept-encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"; "accept-language"="es,en;q=0.9"} | Select-Object -Expand Content
```

I got it from Chromes's Network tab inside the DevTools while watching this site load: https://www.pelispedia.tv/pelicula/el-nino-que-domo-el-viento/

[Devtools Screenshot - also includes cURL and fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ1fc.png)

The response is a full HTML site, which I want to use later.

The fetch script is:

```
fetch("https://www.pelispedia.tv/api/iframes.php?id=18471?nocache", {
    "credentials": "include",
    "headers": {
      "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
      "accept-language": "es,en;q=0.9",
      "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
    },
    "referrer": "https://www.pelispedia.tv/pelicula/el-nino-que-domo-el-viento/",
    "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
    "body": null,
    "method": "GET",
    "mode": "cors"
  })
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(body => console.log(body));
```

I tried using multiple NodeJS packages like `node-fetch`, `axios` and `request` to get the same result as in Powershell, but I simply get an **HTML with the line "ERROR".**

This approach does not work in NodeJS, **but if I run it from within Chrome's console, while I'm from the site, it works.**

I would like to know what Powershell is doing to get the correct response and how to recreate it in Node or any other language/runtime (Java, Python, PHP...).

Answer (score -1):

Using fetch form chrome dev tools and using fetch from node or using Powershell are completely different things.
fetch form chrome dev tools has all the headers and other thing attached to the request as the browser does so it is essentially your browser making the request as perceived by the server of the website.

But in case of PowerShell or nodejs request or fetch, all those headers, referer, and many other things are stripped off. So the server rejects the request considering you a bot.

Comment: I'm able to add the appropiate headers from PowerShell, but I can't do the same in Node. I think I need a way to "translate" the PowerShell fetch to a proper Node fetch, but I'm unable to do it.

Comment: you are very correct. user emulation for the browser is used by bots to crawl and some sites use special bot detection techniques which make it very difficult to crawl the website. I crawl a lot of websites and some of the websites are so well protected by distil or other services that it's very difficult to crawl them.